# Rationalize number

Tags: homework

I must calculate the critical point on the function

```
f[x_] := (x^2 - Abs[x - 10])/(x - 5)
```

After plotting, I looked for the minimum where it looked to be (around 10)

```
FindMinimum[f[x], {x, 6}]
```

Got output:

> {19.9443, {x -> 9.47214}}

and then tried to rationalize x:

Rationalize[9.472135911356355`]

How can I get an exact value?

Comment: The answer by @MariusLadegardMeyer is, in my opinion, the "right" way to go about this. But one can also use the approach in this post, with `RootApproximant` replacing `Rationalize`. `In[269]:= RootApproximant[NArgMin[{f[x], x >= 5}, x]]

Out[269]= 5 + 2 Sqrt[5]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Minimize` with a condition that avoids the divergence to $-\infty$:

```
Minimize[{f[x], x > 5}, x]
```

> > {(-5 + 2 Sqrt[5] + (5 + 2 Sqrt[5])^2)/(
> >      2 Sqrt[5]), {x -> 5 + 2 Sqrt[5]}}

It's the same minimum:

```
N[5 + 2 Sqrt[5]]
```

> > 9.47214

Comment: Thank you Majin Boo, you're best!